# Upgrade Android project to use java 8 and get GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, android, gradle, garbage-collection, java-8

Yesterday when I changed my android project gradle file to use java 8 features:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Every thing was fine. I used lambda expressions and run the project.

But today, I don't know what happen with my project(I reset master to that "upgrading project to use java 8 features" commit). I can't build project. after more than 5 mins android studio shows me an error in gradle console:

> Exception in thread "Tasks limiter_1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

and it stuck in

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJack
```

I noticed that a new file created "java_pid25702.hprof" which is very huge(about 1.5 gb).

I'm using Android studio 2.2, java version "1.8.0_51", Mac book pro (core i7, 16gb ram), OS X version 10.11.4

I also changed my android studio "studio.vmoptions" :

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I see these posts: [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) , [Gradle build hanging when jackOptions is enabled for Java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457116/gradle-build-hanging-when-jackoptions-is-enabled-for-java-1-8) but none them helps me.

My question is 1-why my project works correctly yesterday, but not tody??! 2-what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours and testing project on some other systems, I found that I should update Android studio to

`Android Studio 2.2 stable version`

and also update:

```
Android Plugin version to 2.2.0
Gradle Version to 2.14.1
```

And after that gradle console show a warning that gradle heap size is low, you should increase that by adding:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

to the `gradle.properties` file in your project. and now my project run without any problem.